# GREP only if whole string

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

Here is the list.txt file:

```
001 Linux000

002 Linux001

003 Linux002
```

`cat list.txt | grep 002` returns:

```
002 Linux001

003 Linux002
```

But I need to get only lines where is 002, not Linux002.

```
002 Linux001
```

Comment: sooo `grep -w 002`??

Comment: Or: `grep ^002`

Comment: For a match of _words_, it would be in general `grep -w 002 list.txt`.  Of course this means that your idea of what a word is, is the same as what _grep_ considers to be a word. For instance, the outcome could depend on the locale. Perhaps you should define more precisely, what you want to achieve.

Comment: @MrV : But bear in mind that ceving's suggestion would also match a line `0020 Linux002`.

Comment: cat list.txt | grep ^002
002 Linux001

Comment: `awk '$1=="002"' list.txt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking word boundaries (`\b`) into account with GNU grep:

```
grep '\b002\b' list.txt
```

Comment: Your answer is OK but if I have Linux-002 it won't work, it will display line containg Linux-002 also...

Comment: @MrV. This case is not specified in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Does this `grep` work?

```
$ grep '\<002\>' input_file
002 Linux001
```